# Factorygirl , I can't express the association of 1 on 1 (has_one) with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I want to test #create in Decidingscontroller , and Deciding model has undertaking_id column in association with Undertaking model , and has asking_id column in association with Asking model. 
So, My factories/decidings.rb is below.

```
    factory :deciding do
       after(:build) do |deciding|
        deciding.asking ||=build(:asking, deciding: deciding)
        deciding.undertaking ||=build(:undertaking, deciding: deciding)
      end
    end
```

and My spec/controllers/decidings_controller_spec.rb is below.

```
     RSpec.describe DecidingsController, type: :controller do
      describe '#create' do
       before do
         @deciding=build(:deciding)
       end
       context 'correct_user login' do
         before do 
             login_user(@deciding.asking.user)
         end
         it 'creates with deciding +1' do
           expect{post :create , undertaking_id: @deciding.undertaking_id , asking_id: @deciding.asking_id}.to change(Deciding , :count).by(1)
         end
      end
    end
   end
```

but @deciding in this case is below.

```
    #<Deciding id: nil, asking_id: nil, undertaking_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

so I can't create test because undertaking_id and asking_id is nil.
Why is undertaking_id and asking_id nil? Please help me...
Anyway , My factories/asking.rb  is below.

```
   FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :asking do
      association :user
      sequence(:content){|i| "お願いします#{i}"}
   end
  end
```

Comment: You should use `belongs_to` association instead of `has_one`. However, it's impossible to say exactly, since you don't show your models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ids are nil because the records are not persisted. When you use `build` method, it does not save a record in the database. If a record is not saved, it cannot have ID. Use `create` method instead.

Try this:

```
factory :deciding do
   after(:build) do |deciding|
    deciding.asking ||= create(:asking)
    deciding.undertaking ||= create(:undertaking)
  end
end
```